# MySQL insert fails with '&' character

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting a row in my database that contains text.

The record fails to insert if the '&' symbol is contained within.

The text is taken from a web page textarea and the web page charset is utf-8

My database schema is MyIsam and collation latin1_swedish_ci

The > and the <  symbols also fail an insert

Can anyone advise?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE sections_content SET title = '".$_GET['title']."', content = '".mysql_real_escape_string($content)."' WHERE id = '".$_GET['updateid']."' ";

Comment: The insert and update fails if the text contains the & symbol, I tried an update and insert which were successful without the & symbol

Answer (score 5):

Escape them with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) if you use [mysql_ functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), or prepare your query with PDO.

Comment: Yes, `mysql_real_escape_string()` should do just nicely.

Comment: hmmm that didnt seem to do it my syntax was content = '".mysql_real_escape_string($content)."'

Comment: "mysql_real_escape_string" This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php